# Getting weird 'istream' error in Xcode project all of a sudden

Tags: swift, xcode

Have been working on my project for a while now and suddenly these weird C++ erros start showing. Stuck for an hour now, with no idea about these errors.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Resolved the issue. There was a C++ project on my system. As soon as I deleted that project from my system, everything started working fine. Really weird behaviour by XCode.

Comment: Could you explain what project was that? I have the same issue on my machine.